# tomcat7-maven-plugin behavior with jstl - help using tomcat:run goal

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jstl

There is different behavior when running

```
mvn clean tomcat7:run-war and mvn clean tomcat7:run
```

I am trying to run `jstls` within a servlet 3 container (hence the tomcat 7 plugin) and for some reason when where I run the plugin with the `tomcat7:run` command I get this exception:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to read TLD "META-INF/c.tld" from JAR file "file:/...../.m2/repository/jstl/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar": org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Failed to load or instantiate TagLibraryValidator class: org.apache.taglibs.standard.tlv.JstlCoreTLV
org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:56)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:445)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:219)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.TagLibraryInfoImpl.<init>(TagLibraryInfoImpl.java:182)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.getTaglibInfo(JspDocumentParser.java:1287)
org.apache.jasper.compiler.JspDocumentParser.startPrefixMapping(JspDocumentParser.java:797)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startNamespaceMapping(AbstractSAXParser.java:2164)
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:469)
```

Whereas with `tomcat7:run-war`, I do not. I suspect it has to do with the classloader looking at the maven repository for classpath in the run option versus the war explode location

```
target\[webappname]\WEB-INF\lib
```

The main reason to use run over run-war is hot deploying of changes to the tagx or the JSTL markup.

Here are the relevant pom.xml inclusions:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
          </dependency>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <path>/webapp</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: There are 2 potential problems: JSP is already provided by Tomcat. Mark it `provided`. Group ID for JSTL should be `javax.servlet`. What happens now?

Comment: Ah thanks for the help. JSP to provided was the issue. Now i can do hot swap with tomcat7:run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Was the solution thanks BalusC